# Smart Pointer Basics

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, copy-constructor

I just started using Smart Pointers in C++, and ran into some trouble, but can't figure out where I went wrong. I have a class `Seat`, and `SeatSmart` having pointer to `Seat` class. These are my classes:

```
class Seat{
  public:
     int val;
     int idx;
     Seat(int v, int i):val(v),idx(i){}
};

class SeatSmart{
  public:
     Seat *seat;
     SeatSmart():seat(NULL){}
     SeatSmart(Seat *st):seat(st){}
     ~SeatSmart(){
        delete(seat);
     }
}
```

After this I ran the following code in `main`:

```
priority_queue<SeatSmart> pq;
vector<SeatSmart> q;
SeatSmart sm;
for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
  sm.seat = new Seat(i, i);
  pq.push(sm);
  q.push_back(sm);
}
```

I also overloaded the `<` operator:

```
bool operator<(const SeatSmart &a, const SeatSmart &b){
  return a.seat->val < b.seat->val;
}
```

The problem arises after adding the second element in the priority queue, when the operator `<` is called. The system shows a segmentation fault at that point according to GDB.

The copy constructor should be called when adding `sm` to the vector and the priority queue. Can you please tell me where I went wrong.

Comment: Um, you aren't using any smart pointers in your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)   (with respect to `SeatSmart`)

Comment: You don't need all of that code to see the error: `int main() {SeatSmart s1; s1.seat = new Seat(0,0); SeatSmart s2 = s1; }` boom, you're dead.  No vectors, no priority queues, just a simple copy made.

Comment: “The copy constructor should be called” - what copy constructor? You have not written one. And do be aware that you either need to do reference counting or make your `SeatSmart` move-only (non-copyable). You can read about why `std::auto_ptr` was a failure and how `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` work

Comment: Using smart pointers would *usually* imply using `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr`, `std::weak_ptr` (or in some cases `boost::` equivalents). But you are not using *any* of those.

Comment: Note that because your `SeatSmart::seat` is allowed to be null, your `operator<` will cause Undefined Behavior when dereferencing it